# Saving Word 2007 Document Properties in C# 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, properties, ms-word

I'm trying to modify some CustomDocumentProperties for a .docx document.  I've been able to read the current value and modify it, but when I save the document the changes to the custom fields are lost.

I have the following method within a DocAccessor class (which serves as an interface for my doc files):

```
void SetInfo(string key, string val) {
    object custom_properties = current_doc.CustomDocumentProperties;
    Type custom_properties_type = custom_properties.GetType();
    custom_properties_type.InvokeMember("Item", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, custom_properties, new object[] { key, val });
}
```

elsewhere I call:

```
doc_accessor.GetInfo("Number") //returns 5
doc_accessor.SetInfo("Number", "6");
doc_accessor.GetInfo("Number") //returns 6
doc_accessor.SaveAndClose();
doc_accessor.Open(); //it retains the path, so I don't need to respecify
doc_accessor.GetInfo("Number") //returns 5
```

My doc_accessor.SaveAndClose() function is working correctly as I modified the path to save to a different location and it did... but without writing the modified CustomDocumentProperties.  This makes it seem as if there's a commit step of sorts that I'm missing, but shouldn't current_doc.Save() handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195425

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1xatbkd(VS.80).aspx

i dunno if either of these will help.
but that's where i would start.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documentclass.saved(office.11).aspx

Sorry about the links i've had to remove the protocol heading because stack doesn't think i should be able to have more than one link in my answers because i'm not a real member

Answer (score 1):

I solved 2 minutes ago the same problem.

When you add/change custom properties seems that the document is no `changed`, so the `WordApplication.ActiveDocument.Saved` is still `true`.

Set it to `false` and then call the Save method of the Document, it will work!!